# What does an RSA signature look like?

Tags: rsa, signature

I am using OpenSSL libs to generate signatures. Internally, I learn that a signature is a hash of the message with some padding added to it.
I am trying to understand the structure of a signature. If I use SHA1 as the digest algorithm for the signature, and say a 1024 bit Key, can you please tell me how the signature format looks like?

My code snippet:

```
   const EVP_MD *md = EVP_get_digestbyname("SHA1");
   EVP_SignInit(ctx, md);
   EVP_SignUpdate(ctx, plaintext, plaintext_len));
   EVP_SignFinal(ctx, sig, &siglen, pkey));
```

From the source code I am trying to understand how 'signing' works.  What exactly is added to the hash value before actually "encrypting" it with the RSA key? Assuming the RSA signing takes the RSA_PKCS1_PADDING as default(?),How many bytes of this 'padding' does it append and how does it vary with the digest algorithm?

If I dissect such a signature, how should the bytes look like?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An RSA signature is a sequence of bytes of the same size of the modulus. If the key uses a 1024-bit modulus $n$, then the signature value is, numerically, an integer in the $1..n-1$ range, and the [PKCS#1 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447) specifies that this integer should be encoded as a sequence of bytes of the same length as would be needed to encode the modulus, i.e. 128 bytes for a 1024-bit modulus (big-endian unsigned convention).

The signature process looks like this:

- The message to be signed $m$ is hashed with hash value $h$, yielding $h(m)$, which is a sequence of bytes (say, 32 bytes if $h$ is SHA-256).
- The hash value is *padded*: a byte sequence is assembled, consisting of, in that order: a byte of value 0x00, a byte of value 0x01, *some* bytes of value 0xFF, a byte of value 0x00, a fixed header sequence *H*, and then $h(m)$. The header sequence *H* identifies the hash function (strictly speaking, there are for each hash function *two* possible header values, and I have encountered both). The number of 0xFF bytes is adjusted so that the total sequence length is exactly equal to the encoding length of the modulus (i.e. 128 bytes for a 1024-bit modulus).
- The padded value is then interpreted as an integer $x$, by decoding it with the big-endian convention. Due to the sequence size and the fact that the sequence begins with a 0x00, the value $x$ is necessarily in the $1..n-1$ range.
- The value $x$ is raised to the power $d$ (private exponent) modulo $n$, yielding $s = x^d \pmod n$.
- The $s$ value is encoded into a sequence of the same length as $n$; that's the signature.

To verify, the signature is decoded back into the integer $s$, then $x$ is recovered with $x = s^e \pmod n$, and encoded back. The verifier then checks that the padding as explained above has the proper format, and that it ends with $h(m)$ for the message $m$.

All of the above is the "v1.5" PKCS#1 padding. The standard also defines a newer one, called "PSS", which is a bit more complex, but allows for some kinds of security proofs.

Comment: "The value x is raised to the power d (private exponent) modulo n, yielding s=xd(modn)." Is this where the key is used? Is this operation equivalent to RSA private key encryption?

Comment: In RSA you _never_ encrypt with the private key. The private key is usd to _decrypt_, or to _sign_. The value _d_ must be private, since knowing _d_ and the public key allows for efficient factorization of _n_, i.e. reveal of _p_ and _q_.

Comment: Ok, I am just going through the OpenSSL source codes. I think what I understood is that the hash of the message is computed, it is converted to an X509_SIG object which is then passed to RSA_private_encrypt(isn't this 'private key' encryption?) along with the PKCS#1 as padding info. What is then happening differently??

Comment: Would _`e`_ be the public exponent here?

Answer (score 1):

> What does an RSA signature look like?

I found this in [P1363 Public Key Cryptography](http://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/~guilley/recherche/cryptoprocesseurs/ieee/00891000.pdf). Its an older copy of the standard from 2000. It may (or may not) be current.

On page 41, there is 8.2.6 IFSP-RSA2, which stands for Integer Factorization, Signing Primitive. RSA2 is the second approved method. In the algorithm, the signature is in the range:

> ***Output***: The signature, which is an integer *s* such that *0 ≤ s < n/2*

Keep in mind this is P1363, and not PKCS #1.

---

> I am trying to understand the structure of a signature.

A very good read is Bernstein's [RSA signatures and Rabin–Williams signatures:
the state of the art](http://cr.yp.to/sigs/rwsota-20080131.pdf). Not only does it provide a state of the art, it also provides a good history with reasons for some of the steps.