# Do I need to use AE/AEAD in my particular scenario? Or is it redundant?

Tags: hash, authenticated-encryption, integrity

This is my scenario:

1. A small structured text message (1-2kB) is to be sent over an insecure channel.
2. Everything except for the header portion (which contains a title, timestamp, category and tags) is confidential.
3. The message as a whole has integrity and non-repudiation as additional requirements.

This is how I intend to go about it after having done some crypto-related research:

1. Encrypt the message with AES-CBC/OFB/CTR (key is pre-shared). The IV is added to the front of the ciphertext.
2. Add the non-confidential portions to the output from (1).
3. Make a digest-hash(SHA512 or RIPEMD160) of the output from (2) and encrypt it with the message author's private key (public key is pre-shared). Add that to the output from (2).
4. Send it over the insecure channel.

   ```
   <---IV---><---AES Ciphertext---><---Header---><---Signature--->
   ```

Question:

I know that MAC algorithms and digest algorithms were designed for different purposes, but in this case, my digest is not merely slapped onto the payload, it is asymmetrically encrypted.

So, would the choice of AES-GCM/CCM/EAX have added any additional security? 
Does my scheme have any obvious vulnerability that I overlooked?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDITS:**

1. Fixed a typo. OBC $\rightarrow$ OFB.
2. I did not realize that the hashing algorithms are already built into all the major signing algorithms; I thought you had to do it yourself. Thanks for clearing that up.

**NOTE:** I would have chosen Ricky D.'s advice, but [***comments cannot be chosen as answers.***](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-should-we-handle-comments-that-are-actually-answers)

Comment: Yes, since encrypting the digest-hash [with the message author's private key](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3181/991) is not necessarily useful. $\:$ Instead, the author should presumably [_sign_](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10824/what-does-an-rsa-signature-look-like) the output from (2) with the author's private key. $\hspace{.95 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer I should have been more specific. The one who creates the message (client/author) is the one who then signs it with his/her private key before sending it to the server. i suppose the signing would make sense now.

Comment: Even after your edit, your post does not mention signing. $\:$ A commitment to the AES key needs to be included in what gets signed, since otherwise the receiver could break non-repudiation by claiming a different AES key. $\:$ Additionally, there needs to be only one way to split what gets signed back into its parts. $\:$ (If at most one part is not fixed-length, then the previous sentence will automatically be satisfied.) $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general signature creation contains the hashing part within the algorithm. A signature algorithm may also contain a padding mechanism such as PKCS#1 v1.5 or PSS for RSA. Finally it contains a one-way trap door function (modular exponentiation within RSA). Encryption has other requirements, and uses a different padding mechanism.

Basically you are encrypting a plaintext, and signing all the data including IV within the message. I don't see the need for either a MAC or an authenticated cipher; the signature is perfectly fine as authentication tag. That does not mean that your current scheme does not have weaknesses:

- it does not provide forward secrecy (i.e. if your secret key is compromised, all the messages can be decrypted)
- you have to keep both a private key and share a secret key
- asymmetric operations are expensive (with regards to CPU) and you need a private and public key operation per message
- no signer anonymity (eavesdroppers can prove that messages were sent by a specific sender)
- as others have pointed out, [encrypt-then-sign may have vulnerabilities](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5458/should-we-sign-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-sign) you should be aware of in your protocol

Those drawbacks may be resolved by a careful choice of a TLS cipher suite (if you just require transport security).

Finally you may want to think about how you are going to setup key management.

Comment: The OP's scheme also does not provide signer anonymity against eavesdroppers. $\hspace{1.55 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer Would that be true even if the public keys are not known to attackers? I guess for RSA, with enough information the modulus could be distinguished?

Comment: I would heuristically expect that to hold for RSA even if the public keys are not known to attackers, since I would expect signatures to be distributed roughly uniformly in {1,2,3,4,5,...,modulus-1}. $\:$ On the other hand, it is provably the case that if there are are secure signature schemes then there are secure signature schemes for which the signatures do not provide signer anonymity even against parties that don't have any of the verification keys. $\:$ Also, "messages cannot be repudiated by senders" is a _feature_ (see the upper #3 in the OP). $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Yeah, I think I tried to be a bit too clever there, rewrote anonymity part.

Answer (score 2):

A symmetrically encrypted hash [is not a secure MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3229/is-the-encryption-of-a-hash-a-good-mac). You should use either an authenticated encryption scheme or a secure MAC in encrypt-then-MAC.

With asymmetric encryption, it may be secure – "encrypting" with the author's private key means you are actually signing the message which is fine. However, you need to use the actual asymmetric primitive, not some high level hybrid encryption, because then the hash would actually be encrypted symmetrically. That means security may also depend on your getting padding right etc. so you should use a high level signing interface, if the libraries you use have one.

Had you meant [OCB mode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7253), that would be one option. It should also allow additional data that is only authenticated. However, there are some patent concerns and possible attacks, see the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCB_mode) for some references. Since you meant OFB, it is not a very good mode to use – it's basically [worse than](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/27780/49923) CTR in many ways, but with no advantages like CBC or CFB have.

Another option is to use [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) together with AES in CTR mode (CBC would also work, but is [easier to get wrong](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/27780/49923)). That lets you use any of the hash functions you have available. My choice would be SHA-256 if you have that. This is probably the easiest way available to you, considering you already have symmetric keys shared.

Comment: Care to elaborate WHY an encrypted hash is not a secure mac? How would its integrity be compromised? A scenario where encrypted hash fails would certainly help.

Comment: @P.T. : $\:$ Do you mean a symmetrically encrypted hash, or one that was encrypted $\hspace{1.35 in}$ "with the message author's private key"? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer I meant asymmetrically, i.e. the latter you mentioned.

Comment: The main problem is that I'm not aware of any reason(s) it should be hard to have a significant probability of finding an asymmetric encryption of a random message's digest-hash. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer I meant to use the sign for integrity and non-repudiation. If an adversary flips a few bits and computes a new hash, he does not possess the private key, so his tampering will be detected once on the server. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing that you still haven't edited your question to specify that the author will be signing with the author's private key instead of encrypting with the author's private key. $\;$

Comment: @P.T. I missed the fact that you were using asymmetric encryption for the hash, when the rest of the message used symmetric. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> encrypt it with the message author's private key

This statement makes me uncomfortable. Normally, in asymmetric cryptography, one encrypts with the public key and signs with the private key. Did you mean “sign it with the message author's private key”? Otherwise, I would not accept your protocol without a clear, detailed explanation of what encryption mode you're going to use, and why you are encrypting rather than signing.

If you used a signature, what you would be doing would be encrypt-then-sign. You should read [Should we sign-then-encrypt, or encrypt-then-sign?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5458/should-we-sign-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-sign). [D.W.'s answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/5466) mentions a potential flaw of encrypt-then-sign; whether it's an issue depends on how you verify the message. Anyone can take the ciphertext from stage 1 and tack on their own cleartext header and their own signature. On the recipient side, it is vital that you reject messages where the signature is not made by the party holding the private key: otherwise the recipient may end up decrypting a message on behalf of an adversary.

Given that the ownership of the private key has to be tied with ownership of the symmetric key, I can't see any benefit of your scheme over AEAD. Using AEAD has the advantage that professional cryptographers have pored over the subtle implications of the protocol. A secondary benefit is that symmetric encryption is faster.

One good reason not to use AEAD is if you don't want the recipient to be able to forge messages. In that case, with the caveat above about verifying that signatures match, I think that encrypt-then-sign is ok.